# java bracket stuff and possible XML/XSD questions :)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd

```
// Always I check the ImageAnnotation if it valid based on the AIM XML Schema
AnnotationBuilder.saveToFile (imageAnnotation, "./test.xml", pathXSD);
// Printing saving operation’s result. Instead of using try/catch blocks, you can see the any error message 
// by using AnnotationBuilder.getAimXMLsaveResult() method.
System.out.println(AnnotationBuilder.getAimXMLsaveResult());
```

The above was given to me as part of a tutorial. I turned that into this.

```
public class SaveToFile extends ImageAnnotationInstance {
{
AnnotationBuilder.saveToFile (imageAnnotation, "./test.xml", pathXSD);
       {
           System.out.println(AnnotationBuilder.getAimXMLsaveResult());
       }
} }
```

First of all, are my brackets correct? 
If so, I keep getting an error on the pathXSD part. I'm guessing I'm supposed to put in a path, but am not sure how. Is this a question to ask XML people?

By the way, I'm a Java noob, so sorry if my questions are dumb.

---

update: 
I'm just playing around with the code right now, and tried this out.

```
public class SaveToFile extends ImageAnnotationInstance {
    AnnotationBuilder.saveToFile (imageAnnotation, "./test.xml", pathXSD);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(AnnotationBuilder.getAimXMLsaveResult());
    }   
}
```

Now there is an error with the "./test.xml" part...

Comment: Your braces are not required at all. You should try to read a Java tutorial to learn about Java syntax, first.

Comment: i have taken a class in java so i'm aware. however, when i first did it without the brackets, i kept getting errors in every line, which was why i put them in. however when i put in brackets, it only gives me an error on one part, which is why i am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transferred your code to something that I would see as java code:

```
public class SaveToFile extends ImageAnnotationInstance {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ImageAnnotation imageAnnotation = new ImageAnnotation();
        PathXSD pathXSD = new PathXSD();
        AnnotationBuilder.saveToFile (imageAnnotation, "./test.xml", pathXSD);
        System.out.println(AnnotationBuilder.getAimXMLsaveResult());
    }   
}
```

Since I don't know the classes of *imageAnnotation* and *pathXSD* I made some up. Hope that gets you an idea of how it should look. However I'd also recommend to read some java tutorial, like Rajesh advised.

Comment: let's say that imageAnnotation and pathXSD already existed because i imported stuff. if i took those parts out of your code, does that mean this should theoretically work?

Comment: actually sorry, i just looked at my code. the imageAnnotation was a string made in another class while the pathXSD is something i can't seem to find in the java library given to me. man i just confused myself even furthur